# "Как" в значении "в качестве" в след. предложении

Tags: союзы

"Есть такое понятие как полифазный сон".

Запятая не требуется?

Comment: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_722

Answer (score 1):

Тут нет значения `в качестве`. При значении `в качестве` можно вставить слово `использую` (без слова `такое`). Проверка: использую понятие как полифазный сон. Не работает.

Запятая нужна. Первый пример такой же, как здесь:

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_722